# Theano element wise maximum

Tags: python, numpy, theano

I'm trying to find find the value of
`s=max(ele, 0)` element-wise on a matrix in theano.
I don't have much experience with theano.

So far I have

```
x = theano.tensor.dmatrix('x')
s = (x + abs(x)) / 2  # poor man's trick
linmax = function([x], s)
```

This works, but isn't pretty and I thought I should be able to use `theano.tensor.maximum` for this.

In matlab, to do what I want to do, I would just write 
`linmax=@(x) max (x, zeros (size (x)))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works for me:

```
import theano.tensor as T
from theano import function

x = T.dmatrix('x')
linmax = function([x], T.maximum(x,0))
```

Testing:

```
linmax([[-1,-2],[3,4]])
```

Outputs:

```
array([[0.,0.],[3.,4.]])
```

Comment: Note: `T.max()` and `T.maximum()` are not equivalent. Took me a little while to realize!

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this implemented as

```
s = x*(x>0)
```

several times. Dont know if that's faster than T.maximum()